# Does an electric grill make it faster than a pan?

Tags: cooking-time, roasting, pan, electric-stoves, grill

My teflon pan heats up for several seconds (to roasting temperature). When I tried 1500W teflon electric grill (in a shop) it took much longer. But electric grill is two sided, so parallel roasting of two sides. So what is quicker and how much?

Answer (score 1):

They are different tools.

The main problem with an electric grill (two sided) is that is has a lot more parts and pieces that can break and is harder to clean.

The other big problem of an electric grill, is that it is mostly a single use tool compared to a frying pan that you can use for a ton of different applications.

For example, you want to grill some chicken breasts, you can do it in a pan and in a two sided electric grill; but lets say you want to make a sauce/gravy, in the case of the frying pan, you already have the tool to do it, in the case of the grill, you will have to use another tool  (pot or pan) to do it.

As for the cost, here, in Canada, you can find cheap ones (foreman grill) at around 30$.

Comment: Yup - my 'George' does sausages & cheese toasties [think Breville if you remember those, but bigger] - for everything else I've got frying pans.

Comment: @Tetsujin how old is your grill, I've seen pretty bad reviews when people told that non-stick coating falling off quickly.

Comment: @RS - 15 years or so. It's gone the way of most half-decent teflon coatings; it's not that it comes off, but over time it gets coated with 'burn-on' that you can never satisfactorily get rid of. So it's not as non-stick as it was when new, but it's still fine.

Comment: @Tetsujin great, what model?

Comment: @RS - I've got the one he used to advertise on the TV in the UK, waaaayyy back -  the "Lean Mean Fat Reducing Grilling Machine", model 10032. I bought it for a tenner on eBay & it's still going strong. https://i.stack.imgur.com/18ZgT.jpg